# CSS "hover" shows weird character

Tags: html, css

I have created a sharing box but it is showing a weird character when I hover on sharing buttons:

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoNbq.png

[It is live on here: http://www.dip223.com/uncategorized/aliquam-faucibus-lacinia/](http://www.dip223.com/uncategorized/aliquam-faucibus-lacinia/)

I couldn't find why it is happening. please help.

Comment: Check your html for an _ Also which browser is it showing up in ?

Comment: I am on Chrome. That's the thing: I couldn't find any _ on the html.

Comment: It belongs to `text-decoration` of the anchor tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following element has `text-decoration:underline;` as part of its hoverstate:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Night Life Not For the Faint of Heart - http://www.dip223.com/?p=1075" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 'left=50,top=50,width=600,height=350,toolbar=0'); return false;">
```

Simply adding:

```
.si-share-wmpu a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
```

to your CSS should fix the problem.